# What are the custom URL schemes for TweetDeck and Seesmic?

Tags: iphone

Does TweetDeck or Seesmic have a custom URL scheme that can be used within an iPhone application?  If so, what are the structures of these URL schemes?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know TweetDeck doesn't have one (I've had users ask for this in my app). [Seesmic has quite a complex one](http://help.seesmic.com/entries/182387-seesmic-for-iphone-url-schemes).

See [here](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) for a list of other URL schemes.

Answer (score 0):

TweetDeck's URL scheme is very limited...

```
Open the TweetDeck Home column   tweetdeck://
Open the TweetDeck Me column    tweetdeck://mentions
Open the TweetDeck Inbox column tweetdeck://directs
Open to the search panel    tweetdeck://search
Open a search for "badgers" tweetdeck://search?q=badgers
```